# How to use a while loop to print each line of a fscanf until the end of the file?

Tags: c, file, while-loop

The idea behind this code is to read the input file, which comprises of two digits per line, and then print it out to another file(with some minor changes etc).
I was able to make the code work flawlessly using a for loop, but that only if i know how many lines there are in the file.
The while loop I am using now does not work, any fixes or ideas to how I could repeat the fprintf until the end of the file?

Example Input = 1 2.3
2 5.9
3 2.7
Example Output = Customer 1 has spent 2.3*2.99 (repeated for all customers)

I simply need a way where my loop will repeat my fscanf and print statements all the way to the end of the file.

The loop I have now does not work because of a segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int customer1;
    double cost1;
    int x;
    double totalCost = 0;
    
    FILE * saleInput;
    FILE * saleOutput;
    
    saleInput = fopen("sales.txt","r");
    saleOutput = fopen("recordsales.txt","w");
    
    printf("Retrieving the Records from today's sale!\n");
    
    while(fscanf(saleInput,"%d",&customer1)!=EOF)
    {
        fscanf(saleInput,"%d%lf",&customer1,&cost1);
        
        cost1 = cost1*2.99;
        
        printf("Customer: %d\t", customer1); //yes a tab character was used
        printf("Spent: $%.2lf\n", cost1);
        
        fprintf(saleOutput, "Customer: %d\t", customer1);
        fprintf(saleOutput, "Spent: $%.2lf\n", cost1);

        
        totalCost += cost1;
    }

    fprintf(saleOutput, "-----------------------------\n");
    printf("-----------------------------\n");
    
    printf("$%.2lf was made today.\n", totalCost);
    fprintf(saleOutput,"$%.2lf was made today.\n", totalCost);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: in what ways it doesn't work? it doesn't finish? you get an error? you get the wrong result?

Comment: Hmm... Having 2 `fscanf` successively reading the same `customer1` value is weird, sprecially when you say that your input file has 2 numbers per line. But with no example input, and no actual and expected output I cannot say more...

Comment: I have edited the post to include these things, any thoughts?

Comment: the input should have two values per line idk why it got rid of my spacing when i was editing my bad.

Comment: nvm figured it out pog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 4 problems:

- you don't initialize `cost1`, it's initial value is undetermined, you need to initialize it to 0.
- you're reading the `customer1` value twice.
- you don't check if your calls to `fopen` succeed.
- you should explicitly check that you're reading exactly 2 values, but anyway, `fscanf` shouldn't be used in a real world program as it is impossible to deal with invalid input.

I assume the format of the sales.txt file is something like this:

```
10  15.55
10  23.50
20  100.00
```

You want this:

```
  ...
  saleInput = fopen("sales.txt", "r");
  if (saleInput == NULL) // << add this
  {
    printf("Cannot open sales.txt\n");
    return;
  }

  saleOutput = fopen("recordsales.txt", "w");
  if (saleOutput == NULL) // << add this
  {
    printf("Cannot open recordsales.txt\n");
    return;
  }

  printf("Retrieving the Records from today's sale!\n");
  
  cost1 = 0;  // << add this

  while (fscanf(saleInput, "%d %lf", &customer1, &cost1) == 2) // while we read exactly 2 values
  {
    cost1 = cost1 * 2.99;
    ...
```

Comment: Unfortunately this question was assigned to me with explicit instructions, so adding extra printf statements is a no go :(. The while loop you see in my code is exactly copied from my professor, he made it work and I can't seem to find where mine doesn't. But the one difference is he doesnt call fscanf twice so surely it has something to do with that. Thanks anyways :P

Answer (score -1):

I had to change while(fscanf(saleInput,"%d",&customer1)!=EOF)
to while(fscanf(saleInput, "%d %lf", &customer1, &cost1) != EOF)
and get rid of the extra fscanf inside the loop.
Thanks!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).